# Gitlab CI sequence of instructions causing circular dependency

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CICD configuration that looks something like this:

```
.rule_template: &rule_configuration
  rules:
    - changes:
        - file/dev/script1.txt
      variables:
        DESTINATION_HOST: somehost1
        RUNNER_TAG: somerunner1
    - changes:
        - file/test/script1.txt
      variables:
        DESTINATION_HOST: somehost2
        RUNNER_TAG: somerunner2

default:
  tags:
    - scripts

stages:
  - lint

deploy scripts 1/6:
  <<: *rule_configuration
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
  stage: lint
  script: |
    echo "Add linting here!"
    
....
```

In short, which runner to choose depends on which file was changed, hence the runner tag has to be conditionally decided. However, these jobs never execute and the value of never gets assigned as I always get:

> This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them: $RUNNER_TAG

I believe it is because the rules blocks isn't executed and hence the `$RUNNER_TAG` variable not resolved to its actual value at the point when job/workflow is being initialized and runner being searched.

If my doubt is correct, then probably it's a circular dependency that job initialization requires `$RUNNER_TAG` but the resolution of `$RUNNER_TAG` requires job initialization.

If the above is correct, what is the right way to handle it and what stage can I conditionally decide and assign `$RUNNER_TAG` its value so it doesn’t hinder job/workflow initialization?

```
gitlab-runner --version
Version:      14.7.0
Git revision: 98daeee0
Git branch:   14-7-stable
GO version:   go1.17.5
Built:        2022-01-19T17:11:48+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing is over complicating what you need to do.

Instead of trying to abstract the tag and dynamically create some variable, simply make each job responsible for registering itself within a pipeline run based on if a particular file path changed.

It might feel like code duplication but it actually keeps your CI a lot simpler and easier to understand.

Job1:
Run when file changes
Tag : some tag

Job2:
Run when some other file changes
Tag: sometag2

Job 3:
Run when a third different file changes
Tag: sometag3